# TeleBot: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, api, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Good day everybody! I am writing Telegram bot, using pyTelegramBotApi. 
That's my code:

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN);
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5://154.221.21.197:10800'}
bot.polling()
```

When I try to run it, there is an error:

```
2019-11-28 00:44:10,836 (util.py:66 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "AttributeError occurred, args=("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\util.py", line 60, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 278, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 248, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\apihelper.py", line 189, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\apihelper.py", line 49, in _make_request
    request_url = base_url.format(token, method_name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/bot/newbot.py", line 14, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 391, in polling
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 414, in __threaded_polling
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\util.py", line 79, in raise_exceptions
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\six-1.13.0-py3.7.egg\six.py", line 696, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\util.py", line 60, in run
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 278, in __retrieve_updates
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 248, in get_updates
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\apihelper.py", line 189, in get_updates
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.6.6-py3.7.egg\telebot\apihelper.py", line 49, in _make_request
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What's it and how can I solve this problem? The proxy is working (tried to connect with app), gunicorn, PySocks, pyTelegramBotAPI, requests, urllib3 latest versions are installed.

- IDE: PyCharm 3.0.3
- Python 3.7.4

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Open

> ...\Python3x\Lib\site-packages\pyTelegramBotAPI-3.6.6-py3.8.egg\telebot\apihelper.py

find the line `#49` and commented it. It may not be correct, but it works

http://prntscr.com/q43pne

Comment: Codes are **text**, so post them as **text**.